# como extraer datos de una promise response

Tags: javascript

Estoy obteniendo una respuesta de un api rest como se ve en la siguiente imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código es:

```
  const options = {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'X-Requested-With':'application/json'
        },
        body: 'grant_type=password&client_id=api-stag&username=cpf-01-1xxxxxstag.comprobanteselectronicos.go.cr&password=xxxxx'
      }

    fetch(url,options)

    .then(resp=>console.log(resp.json()))
    .catch(err=>alert(err))
```

Y para intentar obtener el `access_token` ya intente `resp.json().access_token`,
`JSON.stringify(resp.json())`  y ninguna me resulta. Como puedo sacar el `access_token` en esa respuesta?

Comment: En la respuesta dices que estás poniendo acces_token, te falta una **s**, debería ser **access_token**

Comment: Y si simplemente haces resp.access_token ? por lo que veo el rest ya te devuelve un objeto como tal, no tienes que hacer nada más solo acceder a su valor

Comment: @BenderPaisa ya lo hice y me devuelve "undefined"

Answer (score 3):

Te faltaría hacer otro `then()` o `resolve()` porque lo que tienes es una promesa:

```js
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
  .then(resp => resp.json()) //<-- retorna una promesa
  .then(data => {    //<-- falta este then()
    console.log(data)
  });
```

Comment: Correcto. Esa era la solución. Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

El contenido del `body` no está disponible directamente en este objeto `response`, lo que debes hacer es volver a ejecutar un método `then` luego de retornar la respuesta del servidor como un objeto `json`, así:

```
const options = {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'X-Requested-With':'application/json'
    },
    body: 'grant_type=password&client_id=api-stag&username=cpf-01-1xxxxxstag.comprobanteselectronicos.go.cr&password=xxxxx'
  }

fetch(url,options)
.then(resp => resp.json())
.then(data => console.log(data.access_token))
.catch(err => alert(err))
```

Comment: Correcto. Esa era la solución. Gracias.

Comment: @RichardVíquezPérez la verdad lo consulté por que no tenía ni idea jejeje aprendimos los dos! Saludos!